# How can I analyze an exception like this?

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, inotifypropertychanged

When debugging my application I get the following exception.

I know it has to do with an update method for an `INotify` property, but how to find out exactly what's going wrong. I can't get a decent stack call.

The complete exception info is:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233087
  Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'PcgTools.MainWindow' that matches the   specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '9'.
Source=PresentationFramework
LineNumber=4
LinePosition=9
StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at PcgTools.App.Main() in c:\PcgTools\nodes\KorgKronosTools\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0


 InnerException: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
       HResult=-2146233086
       Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
       Source=mscorlib
       ParamName=index
       StackTrace:
            at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
            at PcgTools.Model.Common.Synth.Timbre.get_UsedProgram() in c:\PcgTools\nodes\KorgKronosTools\Model\Common\Synth\Timbre.cs:line 137
            at PcgTools.Model.Common.Synth.Timbre.RefillColumns() in c:\PcgTools\nodes\KorgKronosTools\Model\Common\Synth\Timbre.cs:line 612
            at PcgTools.Model.Common.Synth.Timbre.OnPcgRootPropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) in c:\PcgTools\nodes\KorgKronosTools\Model\Common\Synth\Timbre.cs:line 574
            at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            at Common.Mvvm.ObservableObject.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName, Boolean verifyPropertyName) in c:\PcgTools\nodes\Common\Mvvm\ObservableObject.cs:line 47
            at PcgTools.Model.Common.Synth.Memory.set_ReadingFinished(Boolean value) in c:\PcgTools\nodes\KorgKronosTools\Model\Common\Synth\Memory.cs:line 74
            at PcgTools.Model.Common.File.KorgFileReader.Read(String fileName) in c:\PcgTools\nodes\KorgKronosTools\Model\Common\File\KorgFileReader.cs:line 116
            at PcgTools.ViewModels.MainViewModel.ReadAndShowFile(String fileName, Boolean checkAutoLoadMasterFileSetting) in c:\PcgTools\nodes\KorgKronosTools\ViewModels\MainViewModel.cs:line 367
            at PcgTools.ViewModels.MainViewModel.HandleAppArguments() in c:\PcgTools\nodes\KorgKronosTools\ViewModels\MainViewModel.cs:line 1030
            at PcgTools.MainWindow..ctor() in c:\PcgTools\nodes\KorgKronosTools\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 221
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Do you have the code for `PcgTools.Model.Common.Synth.Timbre.get_UsedProgram()`, or it is a third-party library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of message apeears when XAML initialization triggers erroneous initialization code (at line 4 in `MainWindow.xaml` file). The real cause is described in inner exception. It indicates that in `Timbre.cs:line 137` a list was accessed with an invalid index.

Since, it shows line number for that file, I assume you have its source code, at least in form of a `.pdb` file. Than you can set a break-point in there to see what's going on.

An excellent tool for tracking such unclear exceptions is IntelliTrace, but it's only available for VS Ultimate.

Comment: I feel a bit stupid ... it seems when one copies the full exception to the clipboard it shows more information than on the screen. And when I copied it to here I didn't see the last part which exactly shows the part in my own application that caused it. 

But you fully deserve the solution.

And yes I have that code and know how to debug. Though I haven't heard of IntelliTrace.